# phpmyadmin:5.2.1 Failed to set session cookie

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, docker-desktop

I know others have posted about this problem, but so far none of the solutions work for me. I was using phpmyadmin:5.2.0 with docker just fine until I decided to upgrade my MacOS M1 to 13.3.1 and upgraded my docker desktop to 4.18.0 so that I could use VirtuoFS file sharing.

**System**
docker image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest

phpMyAdmin: 5.2.1

PHP: 8.1.17

MySQL: MariaDB 10.2 (1:10.2.44+maria~bionic)

Browser: same result on Chrome 112.0.5615.121 (Official Build) (arm64), Firefox 112.0.1 (64-bit), Safari 16.4

Docker Desktop: 4.18.0 (104112) using VirtuoFS file sharing

MacOS: 13.3.1 (22E261)

I don't have a VPN or proxy

**Problem**
Attempt signin into phpmyadmin on localhost and I get the error "Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin".

I had no issues logging in until I upgraded to MacOS 13.3.1 and Docker Desktop 4.18.0 and Virtuo filesharing. I've tried going back down to phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.2.0 which was on php 8.0.19 but no luck logging in still.

My PMA_HOST is set correctly in my docker-compose.yml file to my database container.

**What I've tried**

- Clearing all cookies and browser storage (session and local).
- Disabled all chrome extensions
- Tried in different browsers and in incognito
- Changed /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php to try $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';. I've also tried 'config' and setting user/password in the config file. When I do anything besides 'cookie' for auth type, the index page to login doesn't even load. localhost sends no data.
  http and https.
- Restarting my computer
- Re-pulling the phpmyadmin image with no cache

**config.inc.php**

```php
<?php

require '/etc/phpmyadmin/config.secret.inc.php';

/* Ensure we got the environment */
$vars = [
    'PMA_ARBITRARY',
    'PMA_HOST',
    'PMA_HOSTS',
    'PMA_VERBOSE',
    'PMA_VERBOSES',
    'PMA_PORT',
    'PMA_PORTS',
    'PMA_SOCKET',
    'PMA_SOCKETS',
    'PMA_USER',
    'PMA_PASSWORD',
    'PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI',
    'PMA_CONTROLHOST',
    'PMA_CONTROLPORT',
    'PMA_PMADB',
    'PMA_CONTROLUSER',
    'PMA_CONTROLPASS',
    'PMA_QUERYHISTORYDB',
    'PMA_QUERYHISTORYMAX',
    'MAX_EXECUTION_TIME',
    'MEMORY_LIMIT',
    'PMA_UPLOADDIR',
    'PMA_SAVEDIR',
];

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $env = getenv($var);
    if (!isset($_ENV[$var]) && $env !== false) {
        $_ENV[$var] = $env;
    }
}
if (isset($_ENV['PMA_QUERYHISTORYDB'])) {
    $cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = (bool) $_ENV['PMA_QUERYHISTORYDB'];
}

if (isset($_ENV['PMA_QUERYHISTORYMAX'])) {
    $cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = (int) $_ENV['PMA_QUERYHISTORYMAX'];
}

/* Arbitrary server connection */
if (isset($_ENV['PMA_ARBITRARY']) && $_ENV['PMA_ARBITRARY'] === '1') {
    $cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;
}

/* Play nice behind reverse proxys */
if (isset($_ENV['PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI'])) {
    $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = trim($_ENV['PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI']);
}

/* Figure out hosts */

/* Fallback to default linked */
$hosts = ['db'];

/* Set by environment */
if (! empty($_ENV['PMA_HOST'])) {
    $hosts = [$_ENV['PMA_HOST']];
    $verbose = [$_ENV['PMA_VERBOSE']];
    $ports = [$_ENV['PMA_PORT']];
} elseif (! empty($_ENV['PMA_HOSTS'])) {
    $hosts = array_map('trim', explode(',', $_ENV['PMA_HOSTS']));
    $verbose = array_map('trim', explode(',', $_ENV['PMA_VERBOSES']));
    $ports = array_map('trim', explode(',', $_ENV['PMA_PORTS']));
}

if (! empty($_ENV['PMA_SOCKET'])) {
    $sockets = [$_ENV['PMA_SOCKET']];
} elseif (! empty($_ENV['PMA_SOCKETS'])) {
    $sockets = explode(',', $_ENV['PMA_SOCKETS']);
}

/* Server settings */
for ($i = 1; isset($hosts[$i - 1]); $i++) {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $hosts[$i - 1];
    if (isset($verbose[$i - 1])) {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = $verbose[$i - 1];
    }
    if (isset($ports[$i - 1])) {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $ports[$i - 1];
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_USER'])) {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = $_ENV['PMA_USER'];
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = isset($_ENV['PMA_PASSWORD']) ? $_ENV['PMA_PASSWORD'] : '';
    } else {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_PMADB'])) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $_ENV['PMA_PMADB'];
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_CONTROLHOST'])) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = $_ENV['PMA_CONTROLHOST'];
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_CONTROLPORT'])) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = $_ENV['PMA_CONTROLPORT'];
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_CONTROLUSER'])) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $_ENV['PMA_CONTROLUSER'];
    }
    if (isset($_ENV['PMA_CONTROLPASS'])) {
      $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $_ENV['PMA_CONTROLPASS'];
    }
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
}
for ($i = 1; isset($sockets[$i - 1]); $i++) {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $sockets[$i - 1];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
}
/*
 * Revert back to last configured server to make
 * it easier in config.user.inc.php
 */
$i--;

/* Uploads setup */
if (isset($_ENV['PMA_UPLOADDIR'])) {
    $cfg['UploadDir'] = $_ENV['PMA_UPLOADDIR'];
}

if (isset($_ENV['PMA_SAVEDIR'])) {
    $cfg['SaveDir'] = $_ENV['PMA_SAVEDIR'];
}

if (isset($_ENV['MAX_EXECUTION_TIME'])) {
    $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = $_ENV['MAX_EXECUTION_TIME'];
}

if (isset($_ENV['MEMORY_LIMIT'])) {
    $cfg['MemoryLimit'] = $_ENV['MEMORY_LIMIT'];
}

/* Include User Defined Settings Hook */
if (file_exists('/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php')) {
    include '/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php';
}
```

`config.secret.inc.php` contains my blowfish secret. `config.user.inc.php` is empty.

Request and response cookies when I make a login request:
[Cookies sent in the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azF93.png)

Request headers:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpIb21lY2FyZUh1Yg==
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: pma_lang=en; _ga=GA1.1.1072867199.1681835891; _gid=GA1.1.639333758.1681835891; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik9yeXNSdDF0NkNLcnZRNHJRNFRqMkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiajVqaUtXUkFscStRNjhZbmhuSGp5cnN5ZWc2UUdFeWl2TGUyVEg0TnUzU2E3dlNTckxTTjZnaEhtLzZhZ3VGQ0VmZjdlcXk5cGJ6UVlCZm1lSWQzM1RMZy9LTGpxL2E2MmdNN1IrTS9BRlRzRGQwb0x6bDZOaHhyRzMrQkt0bTMiLCJtYWMiOiI2MTk1OGM0ZTBhYjNmZDU2YjMzZmQ0MGE4YTIwMzZlZTYwNTk1ZmQ3MTkwMjdhNGI0ZWJjMjE3OGY1YWY2ZjBiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZuQW5jcFhlTnRtY2JzZjdvOWZqOGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid3EwbFN2cm1IMjVseXRVVDBSbnowRjBySUpPaHdRSzlYU2VBL3Rra0tXUnVKd3BFcUtzU3I1eER6ZnJNRHZHMng3MGhjcDBVeXE1U0RHUnZYRktpL1c0T1JnQWZ0aGMraTNEV21PdUZ2K0Z1TFpjcXhadlUwYURiaDNsalp2WE4iLCJtYWMiOiJmN2VjOGI1ODllOWM1ZDBmZjcxMWJhNTE3MjdmOGRlYjY3NTU3NDUzYjNhN2FiYTE3NzljNDFmM2UwMTMxMWJmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; phpMyAdmin=67af542a66130e884447684575bcee35
Host: localhost:9000
Origin: null
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4510
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' ;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;img-src 'self' data:  *.tile.openstreetmap.org;object-src 'none';
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 17:18:59 GMT
Expires: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 17:18:59 +0000
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 17:18:59 +0000
Pragma: no-cache
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
Set-Cookie: phpMyAdmin=abc82cf002636cb2043274eea4b62b76; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
Set-Cookie: phpMyAdmin=abc82cf002636cb2043274eea4b62b76; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
Set-Cookie: phpMyAdmin=69527678d5d6a5ecd7b9524e13a9c731; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' ;options inline-script eval-script;referrer no-referrer;img-src 'self' data:  *.tile.openstreetmap.org;object-src 'none';
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-ob_mode: 1
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.17
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self' ;script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';referrer no-referrer;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;img-src 'self' data:  *.tile.openstreetmap.org;object-src 'none';
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```